# How to order a has_many association by a column on the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following models:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Items < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :menus
end
```

Each menu needs to have a separate sort order for it's items

I'd normally add a sort_order column on the join table `menus_items`

Do I need to create a new model to store this info and add a `:through` relationship?

What's the best way to set this up in Rails?

Comment: If you want "orders" , yes,  you need to make a new model, in which  you would hold how many items of each menu you want, and the status, etc

Comment: Yes that's correct. You need to add a model to use with the join table, and use has_many :through. The has_and_belongs_to_many is for very simple bridge relationships where you do not need any such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you'll need to create a new `MenuItem` class and associated menu_items table.

```
class Menu
   has_many :menu_items, :order => 'sort_order'
   has_many :items, :through => :menu_items
end

class MenuItem
   belongs_to :menu
   belongs_to :item
end

class Item
   has_many :menu_items
   has_many :menus, :through => :menu_items
end
```

Your menu_items table should have a column for `menu_id`, `item_id`, and `sort_order` (or whatever you are using as the name of your sorting column). Remember though, you need to handle the setting of `sort_order`. You could use the [acts_as_list plugin](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list) or roll in the logic yourself, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks much for the example! Although, the :order had to go on the `has_many :items, :through => :menu_items, :order => "sort_order"` to work